# Flex 3 - import skin from Illustrator : default position problem

Tags: apache-flex, offset, skin, adobe-illustrator

I export a .swf skin file from Illustrator. (For my test i create the default Flex Skin Palette from Illustrator and I export it to .swf file.)

Flex Builder side, the import is successfull (create automaticaly a CSS file).

But, all my components are a default position problem, that is to say, for example i have a button in my main canvas, at fixe position. And when i start my application, this buttons is automatically moved. And this behavior is the same for all component (combo box, text input, etc.).

```
Button
{
```

disabledSkin: Embed(source="assets/test.swf", symbol="Button_disabledSkin");
 downSkin: Embed(source="assets/test.swf", symbol="Button_downSkin");
 overSkin: Embed(source="assets/test.swf", symbol="Button_overSkin");
 upSkin: Embed(source="assets/test.swf", symbol="Button_upSkin");
    }

Thanks for your help

Regards,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

If your using CS5, take a look at this : http://yoavgivati.com/2010/05/flex-skins-registration-points-and-illustrator-cs5/

Basically, your registration point (little "plus" sign) must be in the upper-left corner in Illustrator.

Hope it helps.